# Can set any property of Python object

Tags: python, class, object, properties

For example, this code is Python:

```
a = object()
a.b = 3
```

throws `AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'b'`

But, this piece of code:

```
class c(object): pass
a = c()
a.b = 3
```

is just fine. Why can I assign property b, when class x does not have that property? How can I make my classes have only properties defined?

Comment: `How can I make my classes have only properties defined?` -- It should be pointed out that this is just a lot of extra work for no good reason and perhaps breaking some useful piece of metaprogramming, so it should be avoided unless you have good reasons to do this and know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `object` type is a built-in class written in C and doesn't let you add attributes to it. It has been expressly coded to prevent it.

The easiest way to get the same behavior in your own classes is to use the `__slots__` attribute to define a list of the exact attributes you want to support.  Python will reserve space for just those attributes and not allow any others.

```
class c(object):
    __slots__ = "foo", "bar", "baz"

a = c()

a.foo = 3  # works
a.b   = 3  # AttributeError
```

Of course, there are some caveats with this approach: you can't pickle such objects, and code that expects every object to have a `__dict__` attribute will break. A "more Pythonic" way would be to use a custom `__setattr__()` as shown by another poster. Of course there are plenty of ways around that, and no way around setting `__slots__` (aside from subclassing and adding your attributes to the subclass).

In general, this is not something you should actually want to do in Python. If the user of your class wants to store some extra attributes on instances of the class, there's no reason not to let them, and in fact a lot of reasons why you might want to.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about `__slots__`

Comment: Interesting approach! I was not aware of `__slots__`. However I was going over the caveats to this approach and stumbled upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots. Some good warning are mentioned in that thread. Especially the lack of a `__dict__` method if we use `__slots__`!

Comment: Yes, those are good caveats. A more Pythonic way would arguably to be to write your own `__setattr__()` to disallow unapproved attributes. Of course, using `__slots__` is going to save memory and be faster.

Comment: Edited to call out the pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the behavior of the `__setattr__` magic method like so.

```
class C(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        allowed_attrs = ('a', 'b', 'c')
        if name not in allowed_attrs:
            # raise exception
            # or do something else
            pass
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Of course, this will only prevent you from setting attributes like a.b (the dot form). You can still set the attributes using `a.__dict__[b]` = value. In that case, you should override the `__dict__` method too.

Answer (score 2):

Python generally allows you to set any attribute on any object. This is a special case where the `object` class acts differently. There are also some modules implemented in C that act similarly.

If you *want* your object to behave like this, you can define a `__setattr__(self, name, value)` method that explicitly does a `raise AttributeError()` if you try to set a member that's not on the "approved list" (see http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/389916)

Answer (score 1):

Creating an [`object`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#object) instance has no features.  Therefore setting attributes on an instance of a the base `object` type is expressly disabled. You must subclass it to be able to create attributes.

Hint: If you want a simple object to use as something on which to store properties, you can do so by creating an anonymous function with `lambda`. Functions, being objects, are able to store attributes as well, so this is perfectly legit:

```
>>> a = lambda: None
>>> a.b = 3
>>> a.b 
3
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because when you say `a.b = 3`, it creates a variable in a that represents b. For example,

```
class a: pass
print a.b
```

returns `AttributeError: class a has no attribute b`

However this code,

```
class a: pass
a.b = 3
print a.b
```

returns 3 as it sets the value of b in a, to 3.

Comment: This doesn't answer why he can do `a.b=3` in the second case but not in the first.

Comment: I didn't and I wouldn't, but I have to say it doesn't exactly answer the question.