# Why does object class does not allow attributes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can set any property of Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862159/can-set-any-property-of-python-object)

```
In [67]: obj = object()    
In [68]: obj.x = 42
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/<ipython-input-68-0203a27904ca> in <module>()
----> 1 obj.x = 42

AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'    
In [69]: class myc(object):
   ....:     pass
   ....:     
In [70]: my = myc()    
In [71]: my.x = 42
```

Looks like an inconsistency. How do I make my classes similar to `object` without allowing to add new attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most builtin types do not allow custom attributes, as these come with the overhead of a dictionary associated to each instance.  Custom classes have such a dictionary by default (it's accessible via the `__dict__` attribute), but you can avoid its creation by adding

```
__slots__ = []
```

to the class definition – see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) for full details.